# Create a mysql function that accepts a result set as parameter?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a mySQL function that accepts as a parameter the result set from a query?

Basically I have a lot of queries that will return a result result set as follows:

```
  id   |  score
  70   |   25
  71   |    7
  72   |  215
  74   |   32
  75   |  710
  76   |   34
  78   |  998
  79   |  103
  80   |    3
```

I want to normalize the values such that they come to a range between 0 and 1. 
The way I thought I'd do this was by applying calculation:

`nscore = (score-min(score))/(max(score) - min(score))`

to get following result

```
  id   |  score
  70   |  0.022
  71   |  0.004
  72   |  0.213
  74   |  0.029
  75   |  0.710
  76   |  0.031
  78   |  1.000
  79   |  0.100
  80   |  0.000
```

But I'm not able to come up with a query to get the min and max in this query along with results, hence thought of using a function (cannot use stored procedure) but couldn't documentation on how to pass a result set.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT:
The score field in result is a computed field. Cannot select it directly.

For eg: Sample query that returns the above result - 

    `select t.id as id, count(*) as score 
    from tbl t 
    inner join tbl2 t2 on t.idx = t2.idx
    where t2.role in (.....)`

*just for demo purpose, not actual schema or query*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MySQL doesn't support defining a function with a resultset as an argument.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support Common Table Expression (CTE), and does not support Analytic functions.

To get this result from a MySQL query... one way to do that in MySQL would require the original query to be returned as an inline view, *two* times ...

As an example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , (t.score-s.min_score)/(s.max_score-s.min_score) AS normalized_score
  FROM ( 
         -- original query here
         SELECT id, score FROM ...
       ) t
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(r.score) AS min_score
              , MAX(r.score) AS max_score
           FROM (
                  -- original query here
                  SELECT id, score FROM ...   
                ) r
       ) s
 ORDER BY t.id
```

**EDIT**

Based on the query added to the question ...

```
SELECT q.id
     , (q.score-s.min_score)/(s.max_score-s.min_score) AS normalized_score
  FROM ( -- original query goes here
         -- ------------------------ 

                  select t.id as id, count(*) as score 
                  from tbl t 
                  inner join tbl2 t2 on t.idx = t2.idx
                  where t2.role in (.....)

         -- ------------------------ 
       ) q
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(r.score) AS min_score
              , MAX(r.score) AS max_score
           FROM ( -- original query goes here
                  -- ------------------------ 

                  select t.id as id, count(*) as score 
                  from tbl t 
                  inner join tbl2 t2 on t.idx = t2.idx
                  where t2.role in (.....)

                  -- ------------------------ 
                ) r
       ) s
 ORDER BY q.id
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Forgot to mention an important detail. The score field in the result is a computed field. Cannot select it directly. Editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: A "computed field" shouldn't be an issue. We just need is a query that returns a valid resultset. That full query goes inside the parens. Unfortunately, that same query has to be specified two times.

Comment: Yeah the length is the problem, especially when there are multiple joins. But guess this will have to make do.
Thanks @spencer7593